# How to document.write a quote?

Tags: javascript, document.write

I am trying to `document.write` something to a page using JavaScript.

My HTML currently looks like this:

```
<li data="url: 'page.htm', target: 'Page', item: '4'">item4</li>
```

And I am trying to document.write it to the page.

However I have have a problem tring to include the `"` in the code. I have tired using the following but had no luck.

```
document.write("<li data="url: 'reader.htm', target: 'AccessPage', reader: '4'">4</li>");
```

any ideas how to include the quote mark in the string?

Comment: You know you haven't done your homework when after 1 min you have 3 answers to your question.

Comment: use \ it will give you some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape it.

```
document.write("<li data=\"url: 'reader.htm', target: 'AccessPage', reader: '4'\">4</li>");
```

Comment: I read another post about this on SO that you might need to use the &quot; in an HTML context if the javascript \ excape character didn't do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<li data="url: 'reader.htm', target: 'AccessPage', reader: \"4\"">4</li>");
```

try using scape character..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by escaping double quotes in document.write

```
document.write("<li data=\"url: 'reader.htm', target: 'AccessPage', reader: '4'\">4</li>");
```